TPL Dataflow: Running a pipeline *while impersonated* leaks millions of handles
My Winforms app was consistently crashing to desktop on a large TPL Dataflow pipeline operation. This wasn't caught by the normal try/catch. Only when I put a try/catch at the outermost Program.cs/Main() was I able to catch it: Unhandled Exception: System.Security.SecurityException: Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service. Note that this was on a box with 384GB RAM and 56 logical processors.
I started watching handle count in Sysinternals Process Explorer and saw that my process was grabbing upwards of 14 million handles, but only when I was impersonating. When not impersonating, the same operation only ate 350-400 handles.
It is easy to reproduce this provided you have a secondary account that you can experiment with for impersonation.

Take the sample impersonation console app code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.impersonate?view=netframework-4.7.2
Add the do-nothing TPL Dataflow class provided in this question.
Instantiate a Dummy object once before impersonation, and instantiate another one after impersonation.
Watch loads of handles get created in the Handles view of Process Explorer while impersonated.

TPL Dataflow 6.0.0 and 7.0.0 both have the same problem.
Is there a fix/workaround for this?
    public class Dummy
    {
        const int BATCH_SIZE    = 1_048_576;

        public Dummy()
        {
            DataflowLinkOptions linkOptions = new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true };

            TransformBlock<int, int> transformer = new TransformBlock<int, int>((int x) =>
                {
                    return x - 1000;
                });

            BatchBlock<int> batcher = new BatchBlock<int>(BATCH_SIZE);

            ActionBlock<int[]> actioner = new ActionBlock<int[]>((int[] x) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(x.Length);
                });
            
            transformer.LinkTo(batcher, linkOptions);
            batcher.LinkTo(actioner, linkOptions);

            for (int i = 0; i < 100_000_000; i++)
            {
                transformer.Post(i);
            }

            transformer.Complete();
            actioner.Completion.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("done");
        }
    }

EDIT 1:
@theodor-zoulias's hypothesis was correct in that changing Dummy's constructor to this still triggered huge amounts of Tokens being grabbed by the process while impersonated:
            Parallel.For(0
                        ,100_000
                        ,(int i) =>
                        {
                            if (i % 1_000 == 0) { Console.WriteLine(i); }

                            List<int> list = new List<int>(100_000);
                            list.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, 100_000));
                        });

The behavior of the dummy app from the Gist link below:

EDIT 2A:
https://gist.github.com/amonroejj/43f80da599dac231d18a862ec1dad51c
EDIT 3:
By debugging in dnSpy I could see that ultimately this is down to the Framework duplicating the handle every time it runs a Task. Seemingly user code could have little or no control over this, but there could be mechanisms I'm unaware of.
[pinvokes kernel32.dll DuplicateHandle()]
    mscorlib.dll!System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.CreateFromToken(System.IntPtr userToken) (IL=0x003D, Native=0x00007FF8D33DBE20+0x122)
    mscorlib.dll!System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.WindowsIdentity(System.IntPtr userToken, string authType, int isAuthenticated) (IL=0x0042, Native=0x00007FF8D33DBCD0+0x10E)
    mscorlib.dll!System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.WindowsIdentity(Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeAccessTokenHandle safeTokenHandle) (IL=0x000E, Native=0x00007FF8D33DCFE0+0x62)
    mscorlib.dll!System.Security.SecurityContext.CreateCopy() (IL=0x0052, Native=0x00007FF8D33E1CD0+0x11E)
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.CreateCopy() (IL≈0x007D, Native=0x00007FF8D33E19A0+0x224)
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CopyExecutionContext(System.Threading.ExecutionContext capturedContext) (IL≈0x0013, Native=0x00007FF8D33B5260+0x6A)
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(ref System.Threading.Tasks.Task currentTaskSlot) (IL≈0x00AA, Native=0x00007FF8D33B3320+0x284)
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(bool bPreventDoubleExecution) (IL=0x0063, Native=0x00007FF8D33B3000+0xF4)
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.TryExecuteTaskInline(System.Threading.Tasks.Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued) (IL≈0x000F, Native=0x00007FF8D33B2F00+0x78)
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.TryRunInline(System.Threading.Tasks.Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued) (IL≈0x004C, Native=0x00007FF8D33B26E0+0x143)
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InternalRunSynchronously(System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler scheduler, bool waitForCompletion) (IL≈0x0083, Native=0x00007FF8D33B2160+0x247)
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunSynchronously(System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler scheduler) (IL=0x0016, Native=0x00007FF8D33B20C0+0x85)
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker<object>(int fromInclusive, int toExclusive, System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelOptions parallelOptions, System.Action<int> body, System.Action<int, System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopState> bodyWithState, System.Func<int, System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopState, object, object> bodyWithLocal, System.Func<object> localInit, System.Action<object> localFinally) (IL=0x01A9, Native=0x00007FF8D33A1B20+0x69F)
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(int fromInclusive, int toExclusive, System.Action<int> body) (IL=0x001F, Native=0x00007FF8D33A0280+0xEA)
    ImpersonationTests.exe!Dummy.Dummy() (IL=0x0032, Native=0x00007FF8D33A0190+0xCA)

EDIT 4:
Regarding the commenter question about number of threads, thread count was stable around 180-200 for my real app (not the Dummy app referred to in the Gist link above.)

EDIT 5:
To address some of the comments:

Can you provide a memory dump of your sample to see where the leak is coming from?

https://gist.github.com/amonroejj/c89e2d32c8f6a425d85ac6123d2313f9

Is the parallel for loop ever terminating?

Sure, the Parallel.For from the repro app in the Gist link in Edit 2 runs to completion as expected both pre-impersonation and post-impersonation.

the actual code, that is still not included, uses impersonation improperly

Obviously is it impractical to anonymize and post a large employer-proprietary app, but this is the heart of it:
private async void Run_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Tool t = new Tool();
    
    using (Utils u = new Utils())
    {
        try
        {
            u.BeginImpersonation();
            await Task.Run(() => t.RunPipeline());
        }
        finally
        {
            u.EndImpersonation();
        }
    }
}


this isn't a resource leak

Be sure to review the screen capture gif in Edit 4.

The solution is to use an AD account for the app pool

Since this is Winforms, no app pools are in play.

Perhaps the code runs on Linux and needs to access a database or folder

We're on Windows, not Linux. The impersonation is indeed to let a less privileged user reach both a database and some UNC paths. Since I have sufficient privileges for both, I just commented out the impersonation for now, so that I could run the app to get the work done.

I am not familiar with impersonation, but my guess is that whatever problem emerges in combination with TPL Dataflow, it will also emerge with any other TPL tool, like the Parallel class, the PLINQ library, or starting Tasks manually (Task.Run) and waiting them with Task.WaitAll. The TPL Dataflow is implemented with Tasks internally.

Dataflow doesn't know anything about impersonation. If you see a lot of orphaned items it's because the application is creating them and doesn't dispose them. That includes impersonation tokens. Besides, there's no impersonation in the question's code. It doesn't do anything that requires handles

Please post the actual code. I've used impersonation a lot since ASP.NET v1 and I don't see any using block with impersonation tokens here. Nor do I see anything that uses OS handles, like files, pipes, sockets or anything similar. Besides, instead of creating a new impersonation section for every single operation it's probably faster to create multiple pipelines, one per user.

Another option is to use an ObjectPool with tokens instead of creating a new token for the same user for every operation. Once again you need to make sure the token is released

PS: make sure you pass the tokens with the message along the pipeline instead of expecting them to apply to magically apply to all threadpool threads used by all tasks in the pipeline.

@PanagiotisKanavos The code from the linked Microsoft doc page is the code, verbatim, with just two Dummy instantiations added. Only one impersonation ever takes place, not an impersonation-per-loop-iteration. The fact that you don't see files and pipes is exactly the point of the question. The mere usage of Tasks while impersonated a single time, is generating the Token handles somewhere outside of my code, in one of the Framework libraries. I'm trying to debug this with dnSpy but getting blocked by antivirus.

I asked for your code. The docs show nothing about threads at all. Impersonation affects the thread. Tasks use threads. If you use 100 threads in the same impersonation context you affect all 100 of them. I suspect if you manually created 100 threads inside the same token you'd end up with 100 tokens, similar to opening  connections inside 100 threads or starting transactions inside 100 threads

I can't debug imaginary code and I can't imagine what Instantiate a Dummy object once before and after mean. If you check the Windows API docs on impersonation you'll read Access tokens are objects that describe the security context of a process or thread. and when a thread impersonates a client, the impersonating thread has both a primary access token and an impersonation token.. That OS token has to flow from thread to thread and get reset when the thread goes back to the pool

@PanagiotisKanavos see added screenshot in Edit 2.

Screenshots can't be copied, compiled and run

@PanagiotisKanavos gist link added

ultimately this is down to the Framework duplicating yes, as it should, and the call stack proves it. That's explained in the docs I linked. Tasks run on reusable threads that come from a thread pool. The thread identity is the executing account. When one of those threads is used with impersonation in any way, not just through tasks, the thread has to impersonate the user as well. And when its job finishes, it has to be cleared so it can be reused. Check the ExecutionContext docs too

The problems are caused by the question's code, not TPL or Windows threads. If you want to use thread-local state across threads, it needs to be copied. Explain the actual problem so people can help you solve it

@PanagiotisKanavos: How many threads did your application have when it crashed? The screenshot from process explorer shows token handles are getting added AND removed. This does not look like a straight handle leak.

@AloisKraus see "Edit 4" in OP.

@PanagiotisKanavos: Can you provide a memory dump of your sample to see where the leak is coming from? Is the parallel for loop ever terminating? As far as I can see the exeuction context is only cloned when IsSelfReplicatingRoot || IsChildReplica is true.

@AloisKraus I'm not the poster. I use Dataflow for ETL with millions of records and never encounter such issues. The main reason is that I don't use impersonation to access Windows resources, I make sure the service account can access the resource (file, database, service). The whole point of Windows Authentication/AD is that you don't need to explicitly manage accounts and passwords

@AloisKraus but I do agree with you, this isn't a resource leak. Far more likely that the actual code, that is still not included, uses impersonation improperly. That forces us to guess what's going on and makes it impossible to propose a fix to the real problem, not the symptom. Perhaps AD isn't used at all, and the poster tries to impersonate Windows accounts to connect to a remote machine? That design is the real problem. Perhaps data is stored in a SAMBA server that isn't connected to a domain? That's another problem, solved by setting up Kerberos, essentially joining the file server to AD

Perhaps the Dataflow code runs under a virtual app pool account and needs to access a shared folder or database? The solution is to use an AD account for the app pool. There are virtual AD service accounts similar to App pool local virtual service accounts.

Perhaps the code runs on Linux and needs to access a database or folder? First, all databases can be configured to use username/password combinations. For AD authentication in general Kerberos is the solution, described in the docs eg : Use Active Directory authentication with SQL Server on Linux
